# Do a wildcard query in Datastore GQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I'm trying out Google Cloud's datastore, and have run into a scenario I can't figure out.

I've got two entities of kind `searchterm`, both with a `searchterm` property, one "pink chicken", and the other with "red duck".

I'm attempting to use the GQL `select * from searchterm where searchterm contains "chicken"`
to retrieve the entity that has the `searchterm` property of "pink chicken". However, it doesn't seem to allow me to do that.

I have to fully state `select * from searchterm where searchterm contains "pink chicken"` to get the relevant response.

Does `contains` in GQL not mean what it implies? Would it be possible for me to perform a GQL query that has a wildcard in it to match strings?

Yes, I checked, that `searchterm` property IS indexed.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Datastore does not support such kind of queries and `CONTAINS` or `contains` is just there as equal but it does search substrings. For such cases like yours use the `Search API`.

You can refer this [quote here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference):

> `Notice that the operator = is another name for the IN and CONTAINS operators. For example, <value> = <property-name> is the same as <value> IN <property-name>, and <property-name> = <value> is the same as <property-name> CONTAINS <value>. Also <property-name> IS NULL is the same as <property-name> = NULL.`

And about the fact that datastore does not support this kind of queries refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries):

> **Restrictions on queries**
>   The nature of the index query mechanism imposes certain restrictions on what a query can do. Cloud Datastore queries do not support substring matches, case-insensitive matches, or so-called full-text search. The NOT, OR, and != operators are not natively supported, but some client libraries may add support on top of Cloud Datastore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I actually found that the documentation is quite... unclear. Like the above section you quoted regarding 'contains' operators. I saw it, but had no clue that "contains" in this case isn't the same as "contains" in most other programming languages.

Comment: That's true. I also find learning Google App Engine hard to a lot of unclear stuffs. You will have to read the documentation a number of times. Because sometimes even googling it may lead/direct you to unrelated answers in StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

You can use '%' in GQL, so try filtering the query for '%chicken%' and should bring the results you're looking for.